# RubyMotion Error When Using setTranslucent

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, rubymotion

I'm getting the following error when trying rake a project I'm working on, and I can't figure out why. The message happens no matter what variable I sent it.

```
Objective-C stub for message `setTranslucent:' type `v@:c' not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this message
```

Here's my app_delegate file for reference.

```
class AppDelegate

def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
     navigation_appearance
     @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
     tableView = StopsController.alloc.init 
     @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(tableView)
     @window.makeKeyAndVisible
     true
end


def navigation_appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance.setBackgroundImage UIImage.imageNamed('navbar_bg.png'),
    forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault
    UINavigationBar.appearance.setTranslucent(true)
    UINavigationBar.appearance.setShadowImage UIImage.imageNamed('navbar_shadow.png')   
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not setting the property on an instance of UINavigationBar -

```
class AppDelegate

def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
     @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
     tableView = StopsController.alloc.init 
     @navigationController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(tableView)
     @window.rootViewController = @navigationController
     navigation_appearance
     @window.makeKeyAndVisible
     true
end


def navigation_appearance
    @navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage UIImage.imageNamed('navbar_bg.png'),
    forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault
    @navigationController.navigationBar.setTranslucent(true)
    @navigationController.navigationBar.setShadowImage UIImage.imageNamed('navbar_shadow.png')   
end

end
```

should work!